# how to solve integration using simpsons rule in python?

Tags: python, integration

I have the following assignment: Si(x) = the integral from 0 to x of sin(t)/t. Write a python code that takes the parameter x and returns the sine integral for that x.
I cant figure out how to move forward with my code to make it work. Can anyone help me?

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krist_000\Desktop\integration_simpson.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(simpsons_rule( f_of_t, 2, b, N))
  File "C:\Users\krist_000\Desktop\integration_simpson.py", line 18, in simpsons_rule
    I += f(t) + (2.0*f(t+h) )
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
def simpsons_rule( f, x, b, N):
    *""" Implements simpsons_rule 
    f(t) - function to integrate
    x - start point
    b - end point
    N - number of intervals, must be even.
    """*

    if N & 1:
        print ("Error: N is not a even number.")
        return 0.0

    h = (b - x) / N
    I = 0.0

    x = float(x)
    for i in range(0, N/2):
        I += f(t) + (2.0*f(t+h) )
        t += 2*h

    I = (2.0 * I) - f(x) + f(b)
    I = h * I / 3.0
    return I


import math
def f_of_t(t):
    return (math.sin(t)) / t



N = 1000

b = 0.0


print(simpsons_rule( f_of_t, 2, b, N))
```

Comment: What does "not work" look like?   What happens (or doesn't happen)?  Post results or an error.

Comment: added the error messages now. btw: Im new at python programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm found a few problems with your code.  Your code compiles and runs now.  I get the correct answer, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%28x%29/x%20from%20x%20=%200%20to%202):

```
F:\Tools\python-2.7.3\python.exe F:/Projects/Python/udacity/udacity/simpsons.py
1.6054029768

Process finished with exit code 0
```

See if this works better for you.  You would do well to study the changes I made and understand why I made them:

```
def simpsons_rule(f, a, b, n):
    """
    Implements simpsons_rule 
    :param f: function to integrate
    :param a: start point
    :param b: end point 
    :param n:  number of intervals, must be even.
    :return: integral of the function
    """

    if n & 1:
        print ("Error: n is not a even number.")
        return 0.0

    h = float(b - a) / n
    integral = 0.0

    x = float(a)
    for i in range(0, n / 2):
        integral += f(x) + (2.0 * f(x + h))
        x += 2 * h

    integral = (2.0 * integral) - f(a) + f(b)
    integral = h * integral / 3.0
    return integral


import math


def f_of_t(t):
    # Note: guard against singular behavior at t = 0.  
    # L'Hospital says value should be 1.0.  NAN if you don't check.
    if x == 0:
        return 1.0
    else: 
        return (math.sin(t)) / t


n = 10000
a = 0
b = 2

print(simpsons_rule(f_of_t, a, b, n))
```

Comment: Wow yes! But the answer i get is -1.6...... and in my assignment it says its supposed to be + 1.6.... 

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Yes I understand that the x must be given a variabel, but b must be zero and the assignment says that it has to work for every variable of x

Comment: Nope, you aren't understanding what a and b are.  Those are the limits of integration.  The lower limit cannot be zero.  I've changed it after understanding what you're doing.  The lower limit a is now something closer to zero; b is 2.  You did some bad things with variable naming and assignment that made it harder to see.

Comment: Ok i get it now, thank you so much for taking your time to help me:)

Comment: b is the upper limit.  Change it to whatever value you want.  Sure you have that Simpson's rule programmed correctly?  Doesn't look right.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule

Comment: Don't thank me.  Accept the answer and vote it up.  Your thanks mean little to me.

Comment: The algorithmis from an example my teacher gave on simsons rule.

Comment: This is the right answer; it's what I get from my version of the code:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin(x)%2Fx%20from%20x%20%3D%200%20to%202